# Unable to get Swagger-SpringMVC to run (WAS)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I am not able to get Swagger-SpringMVC to work with the below configuration. Can you please check and advise what am I missing.

```
@RestController
public class MarketingProfileRestService {

    private static final String SPECIFIC = GENERAL + "/{id}";

    @Autowired
    private RestClient restClient;  

    @RequestMapping(value = SPECIFIC, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody   
    public ResponseEntity<Profile> getProfile(
            @PathVariable("id") String id) {        
        System.out.println("Id is : " + id);
        Profile profile = restClient.getProfile(id); 
        return new ResponseEntity<Profile>(profile, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation(){

        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .includePatterns("/.*"); // assuming the API lives at something like http://myapp/api
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "My Project's REST API",
                "This is a description of your API.",
                "API TOS",
                "me@wherever.com",
                "API License",
                "API License URL"
        );
        return apiInfo;
    }
}


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.marketingprofileservice" />


    <mvc:annotation-driven />



</beans>

compile group: 'com.mangofactory', name:'swagger-springmvc', version:'0.8.8'
```

when I open http://localhost:9080/MarketingProfileService/rest/api-docs all I see is

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

I do see that the mapping is correct in logs

```
[4/7/16 16:12:14:155 CDT] 0000007e RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register Mapped "{[/profiles/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.nm.marketingprofileservice.model.Profile> com.nm.marketingprofileservice.service.rest.MarketingProfileRestService.getProfile(java.lang.String)
[4/7/16 16:12:14:155 CDT] 0000007e RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register Mapped "{[/profiles],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Collection<com.nm.marketingprofileservice.model.Profile>> com.nm.marketingprofileservice.service.rest.MarketingProfileRestService.getPersons()
[4/7/16 16:12:14:155 CDT] 0000007e RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register Mapped "{[/api-docs],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.wordnik.swagger.model.ResourceListing> com.mangofactory.swagger.controllers.DefaultSwaggerController.getResourceListing(java.lang.String)
[4/7/16 16:12:14:155 CDT] 0000007e RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register Mapped "{[/api-docs/{swaggerGroup}/{apiDeclaration}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.wordnik.swagger.model.ApiListing> com.mangofactory.swagger.controllers.DefaultSwaggerController.getApiListing(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[4/7/16 16:12:14:171 CDT] 0000007e RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register Mapped "{[/profiles/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.nm.marketingprofileservice.model.Profile> com.nm.marketingprofileservice.service.rest.MarketingProfileRestService.getProfile(java.lang.String)
[4/7/16 16:12:14:171 CDT] 0000007e RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register Mapped "{[/profiles],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Collection<com.nm.marketingprofileservice.model.Profile>> com.nm.marketingprofileservice.service.rest.MarketingProfileRestService.getPersons()
[4/7/16 16:12:14:171 CDT] 0000007e RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register Mapped "{[/api-docs],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.wordnik.swagger.model.ResourceListing> com.mangofactory.swagger.controllers.DefaultSwaggerController.getResourceListing(java.lang.String)
[4/7/16 16:12:14:171 CDT] 0000007e RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register Mapped "{[/api-docs/{swaggerGroup}/{apiDeclaration}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.wordnik.swagger.model.ApiListing> com.mangofactory.swagger.controllers.DefaultSwaggerController.getApiListing(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[4/7/16 16:12:14:251 CDT] 0000007e RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Apr 07 16:12:13 CDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
```

What am I missing. BTW this is run under java 1.6 as our WAS servers run under 1.6. Unfortunately we can't upgrade the java version at this time. I have searched a lot in web and I could not find a complete example for setting up swagger.

Comment: You might want to upgrade to using springfox v2.4.0. It's a newer version of the swagger-springmvc. See http://springfox.io for more details. It even has a migration guide to transition from swagger-springmvc

Comment: Can I use Spring-fox with java1.6?

Comment: Springfox 2.4.0 onwards Java 6 is supported